# How can i get the average time from timestamp between rows in a subselect query?

Tags: mysql

This query returns the date first and the last call submitted to the database per day. Now i want to get the avrg duration between each call submitted in in that time period. but it always return null???

To make it very easy: the normal way to calculate this would be deviding the hours between these two times by the number of calls. How to do this in MYSQL?

Please help!

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(last_call, '%d') AS day, MIN(last_call) AS checkin,
    MAX(last_call) AS checkout, TIMEDIFF(MAX(last_call), MIN(last_call)) AS work_time
    ,(SELECT b.last_call - a.last_call / COUNT(calls.call_id) 
      FROM calls AS a 
      JOIN calls AS b ON b.last_call = (a.last_call + 1) 
     ) AS intv
FROM calls  
GROUP BY EXTRACT( DAY FROM last_call )
```

Comment: Could you explain how do you define an `average time` ? What is, for example, an average time of three timestamps: `2014-10-20 15:20:00` and `2014-12-15 22:33:00` and `2015-01-01 22:33:00` ?

Comment: The Timediff between these two dates is: 838:59:59. The average difference is calculated by multiple of these rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whom soever could need this:

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(MAX(cl1.last_call), MIN(cl1.last_call))) / COUNT(cl1.call_id)         
   FROM calls AS cl1
   WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM cl1.last_call ) = EXTRACT(DAY FROM calls.last_call )
    ) AS 'intvl'     
FROM calls 
WHERE MONTH(last_call) = MONTH(NOW()) LIMIT 1
```